# being that you need to

Tags: prepositions

> Joe: Oh, yeah, yeah, I think I saw something about the eligibility
>   rules **being that** you need to make, uh, below a certain amount of money
>   per year and you need to not have, uh, health insurance.

What does "being that" mean here?

A.J. Hoge Effortless English, Real English Conversation

Answer (score 2):

The underlying sentence is something like "The eligibility rules are that you have to ... " - *that* is a subordinator introducing a clause which specifies the rules (complement of *are*).

This is then converted into a participial clause qualifying "the eligibility rules": *are* becomes the participle *being*, and the complement clause introduced by *that* is unchanged.

Comment: But I wonder why we should use "are" in what you said? Why can't we say "I think I saw something about the eligibility rules that you need to make.."

Comment: @samsam: yes, the noun **rule** _can_ take a _that_ clause as its complement. That is one way of using it. This uses a different construction, and identifies the rules with a _that_ clause using a copula (_are_, _being_). There are often several ways to say things. I find _the rule that [clause]_ much more natural than _the rules that [clause]_.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask what kind of grammar rule should I study to learn more about using "be" before "that clause"? I've never seen such grammar structure before. Anyway, I think both sides of "than" in the line below are the same:   "I find the rule that [clause] much more natural than the rules that [clause]"

Comment: There's no special grammar rule, @samsam: it's just a copular sentence like "I am English" or "The rules are important". Some nouns can be equated to a "that" clause in this way: "The rules are that .... "; "The difference is that ... "; "My conclusion is that ... ". Others cannot: you wouldn't say "My dog is that ... ". The difference in my statement was between "rule" and "rules". I'm happy equating a set of rules (plural) to a "that" clause, but I find using a "that" clause as a complement works better with singular "rule" than plural "rules": I'm not sure why.